# Why there is no indefinite article in this case?

Tags: articles, countability

My workmate, who is a native speaker, sent this email the other day:

> John and myself had birthdays in the last week, and as a result there
>   is **cake** in the kitchen for those who would like some.

I wonder why he wrote **cake**, not **a cake**.

Comment: "Cake" is being used as a non-count noun to refer to the product as a whole, not an individual cake as in "There are six cakes in the kitchen", where "cake" is a count noun. Incidentally, you might tell your workmate that there was no need to use the reflexive pronoun "myself" in his email -- the non-reflexive "I" is all that is required: "John and I had birthdays ...".

Comment: @BillJ Or if the friend were kind enough to leave cake he might decide not to ***tell*** him about the grammatical mistake, but more diplomatically ***ask*** him, as one desirous of perfecting his English, why he used ***myself***.

Answer (score 2):

***The noun *cake* is both countable and non-countable.***

"A cake" can be a large cake which is cut into pieces, and served simply as *cake* (non countable), or sometimes as *pieces of cake* (countable).*Would you like some cake?* or *Would you like a piece of cake?* are both acceptable forms.

Or it could be a small individual cake, which is usually eaten by just one person, and is always *a cake* (countable).

**What your friend left you was non-countable i.e he left you "some cake". However as often happens he elided the *some*. In the same way he may have left *(some)water* or *(some)milk*.**